# recibo null cuando quiero mostrar las información recibida desde mongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Cuando envio el res.json me devuelve esto el navegador o postman:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "usuario": [
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

Tengo 2 usuarios de prueba registrados en la BD cafe, cuando deseo ver lo que contiene en consola (la variable usuarioRegistro) si me los muestra pero no el navegador ni postman, la variable me aparece null.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?, soy nuevo con mongodb y estoy tomando un curso pero algunas cosas que me enseñan están en deshuso.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Usuario = require('../models/userModel');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); 


app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

app.post('/usuario', function (req, res) {
    let body = req.body;
    if(body.nombre!==null && body.email!==null && body.password!==null){
        let usuario = new Usuario({
            nombre: body.nombre,
            email: body.email,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(body.password, 10)
        });

        usuario.save((err, usuarioDB)=>{
            if(err){
                res.status(400).json({
                    ok:false,
                    err
                });
            }else{
                res.json({
                    ok:true,
                    usuario: usuarioDB
                });
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.send("Faltan parametros.");
    }
});

app.get('/usuario', (req, res)=>{

    Usuario.find({}).exec((err, registroUsuario)=>{
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json({ok:false, err});
        }else{
            console.log(registroUsuario);
            res.json({
                ok:true,
                usuario: registroUsuario
            });
        }
    });

});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cafe', {useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(()=>{
        console.log("Connected at BD.")})
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log("Hubo un error al conectar a la BD.")});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is Running");
});
```

En el modelo tengo esto:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uqv = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let rolesValidos = {
    values: ['ADMIN', 'USER'], 
    message: '{VALUE} No es un rol valido.'
};

let usuario = new Schema({
    nombre:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es requerido.']
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El email es requerido.'],
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El password es requerido.']
    },
    img:{
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    role:{
        type:String,
        default: 'USER',
        value: rolesValidos 
    },
    estado:{
        type:Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    googleCount:{
        type:Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

usuario.plugin(uqv, {
    message: '{PATH} debe de ser ÚNICO.'
});

usuario.methods.toJSON = function(){
    let user = this; 

    let obj = user.toObject;

    delete obj.password;

    return obj;

};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario', usuario);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes modificar la búsqueda de esta manera usando el callback

```
app.get('/usuario', (req, res)=>{
 Usuario.find({}, (err, registroUsuario) => {
            if(err){
                res.status(400).json({ok:false, err});
            }else{
                console.log(registroUsuario);
                res.json({
                    ok:true,
                    usuario: registroUsuario
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: disculpa la demora, al final era la función ```user.toObject```, era ```user.toObject()```, faltaba los parentesis. muchas gracias :)